# Why repeating length of list when not using for in range(len(list) in python3?

Tags: python

I am techy101 and I was wondering why my code was repeating a print statement in a loop without even using for in range(len(list)), here is my code:

```py
while True:
    x = input('>> ')
    xL = x.split()
    print(xL)
    result = []
    token_plus = "+"
    token_minus = "-"
    token_multiply = "*"
    token_divide = "/"
    for token_plus in xL:
        num1 = xL.index("+")
        print(num1)
```

when I run it, it gives this output:

```py
>> 1 + 1
['1', '+', '1']
1
1
1
>>
```

why is it doing this?

Comment: Have a look how for loop iterates over list values. `range(len(list)` is not only way to run loop on lists. You are iterating over values of `xL` in your code.

Comment: @Ank can you please explain more? I'm kinda new to python.

Comment: It will iterate the number of times there are elements in `xL`. Thats how looping in Python works. But why are you using the loop, it does not make sense.

Comment: Look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

```
for token_plus in xL
```

Means do job inside loop for every item in xL and xL has 3 item so it print 3 times.

Comment: how because I am saying token_plus so basically for every "+" in xL

Comment: if you print token_plus inside loop you will understand. You are not giving token_plus as a parameter when you write **for token_plus in xL** this means  iterate every item in xL to token_plus and use inside loop one by one.

Answer (score 1):

`for token_plus in xL:` assigns `token_plus` to the element value for each element in `xL`. So your loop is going through all three indexes in `xL` and thus printing 1 three times.

EDIT:
To help clarify, the first loop, `token_plus` is assigned to `1`. Second loop it is assigned to `+`. Third loop it is assigned to `1`. For each of these three loops, the code within your for loop is executed, thus printing the index of `+` in `xL`, which is `1` in all three cases.

Answer (score 1):

`xL` is a list, So when you are using:

```
for token_plus in xL:
        num1 = xL.index("+")
        print(num1)
```

What it does is iterate through each element in `xL`, So you don't always have to define a `range()` to have a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What `range()` function do is actually returns a sequence and python loop iterate over the sequence. For example `range(3)` returns a sequence of value with 0,1,2 and for loop will run 3 times for each element in the sequence.

You are doing just this -

```
for token_plus in xL:
```

here xL is a sequence (list is a sequence; you might wanna read about this). As it has 3 elements your for loop is running 3 times and printing the index of '+' element.